# Can there still be infinite recursion if I remove all left recursion?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, left-recursion

I have to transform the following grammar into a non left recursive grammar:

S →  aSb | bAS

A →  AaA | bAA | AAa | bAb

This is what I came up with:

A → bAAA’| bAbA’

A’ → aAA’| AaA’| ε

S →  aSb | bAS

As far as I can tell, there is no more left recursion because none of the leftmost symbols on the RHS are the same as the nonterminal on the left. However, assuming S is the starting symbol, there is still infinite recursion because A calls itself repeatedly. Is this expected? Or did I derive the non left recursive grammar incorrectly?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Can you double check the original problem? Can you edit the question to add a reference to the source of the original problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following rule in the original grammar.
$\quad S \to aSb \mid bAS$
If you start generation from $S$, you cannot get rid of $S$.
$\quad A \to AaA \mid bAA \mid AAa \mid bAb $
If you continue applying production rules from a sentential form that contains $A$, you cannot get rid of $A$, either.

These rules are called unproductive rules. Unproductive rules and unreachable rules are called [useless rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_rules). You may take a look at [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69215/can-there-be-dead-states-in-a-context-free-grammar).

If there are useless rules in the original grammar, there will be useless rules after the transformation by [pure left-recursion removal procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion). That is why you see "there is still infinite recursion because $A$ calls itself repeatedly". There is nothing wrong with your transformation to that non-left-recursive grammar.

Those useless production rules can be remove by [some algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_rules#Cleaning_Useless_Rules).
We can see that the original grammar in the question will become empty after such cleaning. Indeed, the original grammar generates the empty language, the language that contains no words.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I learned something new.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to be helpful.